# Select whole array from ->getProduct()

Tags: product, magento-1, event-observer

I have this in my **observer:**

**$product = $observer->getProduct();**

If I do var_dump($product) I get the following:

```
object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)[88]
protected '_cacheTag' => string 'catalog_product' (length=15)
protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'catalog_product' (length=15)
protected '_eventObject' => string 'product' (length=7)
protected '_canAffectOptions' => boolean false
protected '_typeInstance' => null
protected '_typeInstanceSingleton' => null
protected '_linkInstance' => null
protected '_customOptions' => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
protected '_urlModel' => null
protected '_errors' => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
protected '_optionInstance' => null
protected '_options' => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
protected '_reservedAttributes' => null
protected '_isDuplicable' => boolean true
protected '_calculatePrice' => boolean true
protected '_defaultValues' => 
  array (size=1)
    'url_path' => string 'baden-elite-indoor-game-basketball-  nfhs-approved.html' (length=53)
protected '_storeValuesFlags' => 
  array (size=1)
    'url_path' => boolean true
protected '_lockedAttributes' => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
protected '_isDeleteable' => boolean true
protected '_isReadonly' => boolean false
protected '_resourceName' => string 'catalog/product' (length=15)
protected '_resource' => null
protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'catalog/product_collection' (length=26)
protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
protected '_isObjectNew' => null
protected '_data' => 
  array (size=52)
    'store_id' => string '1' (length=1)
    'entity_id' => string '12418' (length=5)
    'entity_type_id' => string '4' (length=1)
    'attribute_set_id' => string '4' (length=1)
    'type_id' => string 'simple' (length=6)
    'sku' => string '28748_SKUPO' (length=11)
    'has_options' => string '0' (length=1)
    'required_options' => string '0' (length=1)
    'created_at' => string '2017-05-10T09:33:40+03:00' (length=25)
    'updated_at' => string '2017-05-10 07:15:52' (length=19)
    'name' => string 'Baden Elite Indoor Game Basketball, NFHS Approved' (length=49)
    'meta_title' => null
    'meta_description' => null
    'image' => string 'no_selection' (length=12)
    'small_image' => string 'no_selection' (length=12)
    'thumbnail' => string 'no_selection' (length=12)
    'url_key' => string 'baden-elite-indoor-game-basketball-nfhs-approved' (length=48)
    'url_path' => string 'baden-elite-indoor-game-basketball-nfhs-approved.html' (length=53)
    'custom_design' => null
    'page_layout' => null
    'options_container' => string 'container1' (length=10)
    'country_of_manufacture' => null
    'msrp_enabled' => string '2' (length=1)
    'msrp_display_actual_price_type' => string '4' (length=1)
    'gift_message_available' => null
    'price' => string '46.6300' (length=7)
    'special_price' => null
    'weight' => string '500.0000' (length=8)
    'msrp' => null
    'status' => string '1' (length=1)
    'is_recurring' => string '0' (length=1)
    'visibility' => string '4' (length=1)
    'tax_class_id' => string '4' (length=1)
    'description' => string 'ELITE - Baden’s Top-of-the-line indoor game     (length=29)
    'meta_keyword' => null
    'custom_layout_update' => null
    'special_from_date' => null
    'special_to_date' => null
    'news_from_date' => null
    'news_to_date' => null
    'custom_design_from' => null
    'custom_design_to' => null
    'group_price' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
    'group_price_changed' => int 0
    'media_gallery' => 
      array (size=2)
        'images' => 
          array (size=0)
            ...
        'values' => 
          array (size=0)
            ...
    'tier_price' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
    'tier_price_changed' => int 0
    'stock_item' => 
      object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)[238]
        private '_minSaleQtyCache' => 
          array (size=0)
            ...
        protected '_qtyIncrements' => null
        protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'cataloginventory_stock_item' (length=27)
        protected '_eventObject' => string 'item' (length=4)
        protected '_productInstance' => 
          &object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)[88]
        protected '_customerGroupId' => null
        protected '_processIndexEvents' => boolean true
        protected '_resourceName' => string 'cataloginventory/stock_item' (length=27)
        protected '_resource' => null
        protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'cataloginventory/stock_item_collection' (length=38)
        protected '_cacheTag' => boolean false
        protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
        protected '_isObjectNew' => null
        protected '_data' => 
          array (size=33)
            ...
        protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
        protected '_origData' => 
          array (size=28)
            ...
        protected '_idFieldName' => string 'item_id' (length=7)
        protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
        protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
          array (size=2)
            ...
        protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
          array (size=4)
            ...
    'is_in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
    'is_salable' => string '1' (length=1)
    'website_ids' => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => string '1' (length=1)
protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
protected '_origData' => null
protected '_idFieldName' => string 'entity_id' (length=9)
protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
  array (size=0)
    empty
```

Now I can access lets say the price like that: **$product->price**

And it works like that but what do I have to do to get the whole array? In this case it's called **_data**.

I tried to access the whole array like **$product->_data** but this didn't work.

Comment: Try with $product->getData()

Comment: $product = $observer->getProduct()->getData();

Comment: This getData() isn't working.

Comment: Which event are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access complete product data via:

```
$product = $observer->getProduct()->getData();
```

**Edit:**

`getName()` does not work anymore, because `$product` is an array now ... so use this:

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$data    = $product->getData();

$name    = $product->getName();
```

or:

```
$name    = $data['name'];
```

Comment: So yeah this is working now. But I'm having another issue. I can't access the data in the array individually anymore. If I do **$product->getName()**  for example it says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on array". Accessing them like that without this ->getData() added works tho. But I need to keep this ->getData(). Is there a way different than this ->getName() to access them?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
var_dump($product->getData());
```